# how to get a redirect with HTTP POST

Tags: http, authentication, http-post, http-status-codes, http-redirect

I try to Login at a website with a HTTP POST. It doesn´t work, I get the status Code 200 instead of 303. Which mistakes could be the reason for that?

Comment: There's no standard reason for this, so it highly depends on the website.

Answer (score 0):

The typical explanation is that the website is designed to respond with the login page, if the authentication failed. A 200 can indicate that page content is available and returned successfully, while the page content indicates that the login failed. The most likely reason for this is browser compatibility, whereby some non-standard browsers might react differently to non-200 responses.